# Returning an array from a PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I query my database with a PHP script that looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM JKFactory WHERE ronde = '$ronde' AND moment =   '$moment' AND klas = '$klas'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo $row['afzetAG'];
    echo ",";
}
```

This gives a result something like this:

> 10000,20000,30000,

I need this data to build a **piegraph** with **chart.js**.
chart.js works with arrays for the data. So the numbers should be returned as an array which I can put into an JavaScript variable which I can use with chart.js.

Another problem is the last comma. I have no idea how I can get rid of this comma.

Maybe these question are straightforward but I am relatively new in this field I really get stuck on this part.

Comment: You coudld use `$num_rows= mysql_num_rows($result);` to get the number of rows returned. From there you can keep track of the counter in the while loop, thus you know when to skip the comma at the end.

Answer (score 0):

To print your result like 1000,2000,3000... You can save the content into an Array and print it using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   array_push($data, $row['afzetAG']);
}
echo implode(",",$data);
```

But if you want to use an Array from PHP to JavaScript you can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   array_push($data, $row['afzetAG']);
}
?>
var obj = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```

So now `obj` contains the Array ready to use in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question. The second code. I put that in my php file?

Comment: Well, yes if in that PHP file you have your call to chart.js as well. I mean, I guess you have a PHP file with the HTML, and the <script src="path-to-chart.js"></script>. So the second code prepares a JS variable with the data as an Array, as you asked for to send it to the chart function.

Answer (score 0):

You have the array and you'd put the comma after the results yourself. so try to declare an `array` like `$arr` before `while` and use `array_push($arr,$row['afzetAG'])` inside the `while`

Answer (score 0):

```
$types = array(); 
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) { $types[] = $row['type']; }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

ok i made it. To echo the result i used this:

```
 $a = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $b = $row['afzetAG'];
 array_push($a,$b);

 }
echo implode(",",$a);
```

This gives not an array i can use in javascript. In javascript i put the result in a variable myResult and than i used:

```
myResult = myResult.split(',');
```

this i could use in chart.js to build a pie chart.

Thanks guys. Now i can sleep.